# Is it possible to create a screwless cube made out of 12 individual planks?

Tags: geometry

The planks all have to be identical. But I'm trying to figure out if there is a configuration in which it can be created. Below is an example of a screwless square shape. This cube needs to be able to be assembled, not just fit together.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CQFS.png)

Comment: dovetails within dovetails ?

Comment: With really identical planks, this may be a bit difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no, and though I am not equipped to provide you with a proof, I can give you a rather lengthy explanation.

When you assemble your two-dimensional example in a plane, the entire reason that it is *rigid* is because it can't be unassembled *in the plane*, and to assemble it, you must lift the pieces *out of the plane*, and then place them back down. However, in order to assemble a cube in an analogous way, you need to be able to pull the pieces into the fourth dimension.

As for @RoddyMacPhee's answer, I don't believe that you can assemble the walls of a cube such that each wall is connected to each other wall using dovetails. Such a cube would be *impossible* to take apart without destroying it, suggesting that it would not be assemble-able.

**TLDR:** No, unless you are a fourth-dimensional being.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you think the same applies if we use 2 planks (sides) as one, so there are only 6 pieces that need to be identical and fit together? Or even 3, 4 or 6 sides already connected? I could imagine it being possible if 6 of the sides are already connected by sliding them together diagonally.

Comment: Yes, that might work...

Comment: After working on it a bit more in SketchUp I've found it's almost possible, if the cube was made out of rubber instead of wood with flexible properties it could work. http://imgur.com/a/sMPT1 @Nominal Animal: Thanks for your last comment, I hope I could try something like that on a small scale soon.

Comment: @Alanay: If the *planks* in the question refers to a material like pine: It is possible to severely deform the wood by boiling it in water, and then applying compression. After it has cooled down, boiling it again in water will re-form the wood to roughly its original shape. This is used in the construction of many wooden puzzles. Very little deformation is needed to construct a locking structure; usually, boiling in water is not necessary, as wood does flex a little, especially in the transverse direction.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Good point, but I was assuming that the cube would be made of a rigid material.